# ngx-bootstrap tabs don't work in modal opened through leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-leaflet

Relevant code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-leaflet-tests-kz7kc7
When you click on a marker, modal opens but tabs inside don't work. There is some problem with angular change detection. It works if I manually detect changes. How can I open modal so it would "stay connected" to angular's change detection?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently angular has zones and leaflet runs some code outside of angular's change detecting zone. According to [this](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#a-note-about-change-detection), there is an easy fix and it [works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-leaflet-tests-k1et7z).